# import tensorflow error using sublime text 3

Tags: macos, python-3.x, tensorflow, sublimetext3

When I import tensorflow using sublime3 python3 on macOS 10.12, I get the error:

> ImportError: No module named 'pywraptensorflow'

However, I can import the library and run my script smoothly in terminal. Why does this occur?

I am using the following build system, and python3 alone works well in sublime.

```
    {
"cmd": ["/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3", "-u", "$file"],
"file_regex": "^[ ]File \"(...?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
"selector": "source.python"
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3217)?

Comment: Thanks for the link! I have found a solution, for anyone has the same problem: it is caused by sublime didn't use the terminal's bash profile, after I launched sublime from terminal, it works.

Answer (score 0):

OP self-solved the problem:  Sublime was not honoring the bash_profile settings when not launched from terminal.  Solution:  Launch sublime from a terminal window.